# perl zip directory empty

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use Archive::Zip to zip a directory but the resulting zip I get is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

```
   my ($inDirectory, $outFile) = @_;

   # Create a Zip file
   my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

   # Add a directory
   my $dir_member = $zip->addDirectory($inDirectory. "/");

   # Save the Zip file
   unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed($outFile) == AZ_OK ) {
       die 'Could not zip file';
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working , I had to use $zip->addTree

Comment: Right, calling `addDirectory` just adds an empty directory entry to the zip file, you have to add the files separately or use a convenience method such as `addTree`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your directory *$inDirectory* ... is not a directory as expected and I'm not sure but it looks like you don't need the end slash for the dirname  :

```
print $inDirectory::Find::name;
if ( -d $inDirectory::Find::name ) { # just grab directories, not files.
   print "adding a dir\n";
   $zip->addDirectory($inDirectory::Find::name);
} else {
  #zip files
   print "adding a file\n";
  $zip->addFile($inDirectory::Find::name) != AZ_OK ||  print "couldn't add file \n";
}
```